# Graph api upgrading to v2.0 from 1.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On my web site users can login with facebook.If user logins with facebook i am getting his facebook profile photo to my site with this line:

```
$img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user->facebook_id.'/picture?width=400');
```

But I am getting alert now, Facebook says you are using graph api v1.0 you need to upgrade to v2.0 What should I do to this code for upgrade to v2.0 ?

**Alert:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your App Migration settings: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your-app-id}/settings/migrations/`

In there, you can select "Use Graph API v2.0 by default".

Comment: But it says you are using v1.0 . if i do that will my site break ?

Comment: your site will break anyway, if you still rely on v1.0, because it will be disabled in a few days.

Comment: If you switch now and see that something breaks you can switch back while you fix it. If you wait until 4/30/2015 it will automatically switch and you can't switch back if something breaks